# passing arrays to C functions to update structs

Tags: c, function, struct, enums

I'm doing an assignment at uni based on the gomoku game.

As part of the process I initialise a gameboard, then I initialise a game, these are structs defined in header files and we have to use defined calls and not use global variables (or lose marks), but I'm a bit confused about the process:

The header file:

```
struct game
{
 struct player players[NUM_PLAYERS];
 board gameboard;
 struct player* current, *other;
};

enum input_result init_game(struct game*);

void play_game(void);
```

board header file

```
enum cell
{
  C_EMPTY,
  etc...
};

typedef enum cell board[BOARDHEIGHT][BOARDWIDTH];

void init_board(board);
```

in main

I've created the board (2d array) called bd, initialised it fine and then added values to each cell in a separate c file

in game.c file
I've initialised the game structure and called the function, 
passing the address of the game struct

```
struct game curgame;
init_game(&curgame);
```

the issue I'm having is passing the board to the struct:

```
enum input_results init_game(struct game* newgame)
{
  newgame.board = bd;

}
```

This is incorrect and I'm getting errors saying:

newgame is undeclared (first use in this function)
bd is undeclared (first use in this function)

Could someone explain to me like I'm a five year old, how to pass the values to the function so I can add them to a struct, without editing the call to the function?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your newgame is a pointer to a structure, to use member use `->` instead of `.`
`newgame->board = bd`

Comment: Where does `bd` come from?

Answer (score 3):

First, `newgame` is a pointer to a struct, not a struct, so you can't use the member access operator `.` on it.  You instead need the pointer to member operator `->` to access the members.

Second, because the `gameboard` member is an array, you can't assign to it directly.  Instead, pass `newgame->gameboard` to the function that initializes the board.